# How do I get the subscripted class of instantiated `types.GenericAlias`?

Tags: python-3.x, python-typing

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) on subscripting a generic class, `list[str]` will return a `types.GenericAlias` with the subscripted type of `list`.

However, I cannot find a pythonic way of extracting this generic class from the instantiated `types.GenericAlias`.

What is the most pythonic way to get the generic class `list` from `list[str]`?

The only (hacky) way I can think of is this:

```
def is_list(type_: types.GenericAlias) -> bool:
    return str(type_).startswith("list")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [typing.get_origin](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin) - this is exactly what you need.

```
get_origin(list[int]) # <class 'list'>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the `list` class from `list[str]` by instantiating the type. According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#types-genericalias):

```
t = list[str]
type(t)  # <class 'types.GenericAlias'>

l = t()
type(l)  # <class 'list'>
```

Comment: And now suppose it was an `abc.ABC` with `abstractmethod`s or has `__init__` side effects... (Downvote mine, because this is very dangerous)

Comment: If it was a custom subclass I could've just set the subscripted class as an attribute. Please upvote the question for visibility if quoting the documentation is not a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I have to agree with @SUTerliakov-supportsstrike on this. Instantiating a class to figure out what it is seems an even worse idea than just checking its name. The documentation you linked does not show this as a viable method to solve your problem. It presents this as an example for how the type arguments passed to generic alias types are erased upon instantiation. In any case, the [`__origin__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/typing.py#L1320) attribute is what you are looking for and @RobinGugel's answer shows how you can reliably get it.

Comment: I must agree. I've also noticed this method does not play nice with `typing.Union` as these cannot be instantiated. Using `get_origin` on said class does work (somewhat) however.